# How can I find the L6562AD simulation model for LTspice?

Tags: integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, mosfet-driver

I understand how to import a LIB file that contains ".SUBCKT" as a symbol into LTspice. But the question is how to find the LIB file (especially for L6562A).

The STMicroelectronics provides a bunch of models as follows; which one is applicable for LTspice and how to import it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Those are for PCB software, not simulation, so it doesn't look like there is a SPICE model. You could try to email them and ask if they have one or if they are willing to make one.

Comment: But the symbol is also presented (I've just attached) but there is not any direct link to download. Isn't the spice models available under cadence tab?

Comment: Is there any other alternative website to achieve spice libraries?

Comment: @Kamran Well, making your own model is an alternative.

Comment: Life is too short to do that bro.

Comment: @Kamran What did they say, do they have a model, or are they willing to make one? If you can't find someone who made such a model, you're stuck on making your own. On the bright side it looks easy enough (given LTspice's A-devices).